# Some enigmatic number sequences

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence

Here are some numbers:
959, 233, 14, 36, 105, 45, 784, 120, 1579, 1001, 1111, 90, 841, 1607, 590, 625, 609, 144, 606
And here are the rest of the numbers:
1, 2, 5, 20, 30, 34, 42, 55, 56, 66, 72, 78, 89, 91, 132, 136, 153, 377, 429, 512, 595, 598, 602, 610, 676, 729, 900, 949, 969, 979, 987, 989, 999, 1000, 1221, 1331, 1583, 1597, 1601

**What do I hope that this puzzle can be for other number sequence puzzles?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These numbers are all

> part of multiple different sequences. For instance, we have 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, and 153: all triangular numbers.

This might be hard to get a foothold on normally, but

> examining the post (by clicking "edit") shows us that an image has been uploaded but left out of the post.
>
>  [image]
>
>  This image helpfully gives us the lengths of all the sequences, *and* where they intersect! (For instance, the Fibonacci numbers are the top most long bar, and they share a number with three other sequences.)

So we can find all the partial sequences:

> Fibonacci numbers: 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597
>  Triangular numbers: 36, 45, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153
>  [Sphenic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphenic_number): 590, 595, 598, 602, 606, 609, 610
>  Prime numbers: 1579, 1583, 1597, 1601, 1607
>  [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number): 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429
>  [Oblong numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number): 20, 30, 42, 56, 71, 90
>  Square numbers: 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900
>  Cube numbers: 512, 729, 1000, 1331
>  Palindrome numbers: 949, 959, 969, 979, 989, 999, 1001, 1111, 1221, 1331

Next, we notice that

> these partial sequences are all the exact same length as the words describing them. ("Palindrome" has 10 letters, and there are 10 palindrome numbers.) Turns out they even *intersect* in the exact same way!
>  [image]  [image]
>
>  Take the numbers in the first sequence (which I've highlighted green) and read off their corresponding letters, and we see that this puzzle is clearly **A NATURAL PROGRESSION**.

Comment: Dang....I was on your step two when you posted this answer...

Comment: Reading the answer I turned from "Oh, well, yet another - possibly ambiguous - number sequence" to "Wow, that is really amazing and well constructed!". Great puzzle, and great answer!